# Panic error on google cloud TPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, panic, google-cloud-tpu

I can open a ctpu session and get the code I need from my git repository, but when I run my tensorflow code from the cloud shell, I get a message to say that there is no TPU and my program crashes. Here is the error message I get:

```
adrien_doerig@adrien-doerig:~/capser$ python TPU_playground.py
(unset)
INFO:tensorflow:Querying Tensorflow master () for TPU system metadata.
2018-07-16 09:45:49.951310: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
INFO:tensorflow:Failed to find TPU: _TPUSystemMetadata(num_cores=0, num_hosts=0, num_of_cores_per_host=0, topology=None, devices=[_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 268435456)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "TPU_playground.py", line 79, in <module>
capser.train(input_fn=train_input_fn_tpu, steps=n_steps)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 363, in train
hooks.extend(self._convert_train_steps_to_hooks(steps, max_steps))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_estimator.py", line 2068, in _convert_train_steps_to_hooks
if ctx.is_running_on_cpu():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_context.py", line 339, in is_running_on_cpu
self._validate_tpu_configuration()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/tpu_context.py", line 525, in _validate_tpu_configuration
'are {}.'.format(tpu_system_metadata.devices))
RuntimeError: Cannot find any TPU cores in the system. Please double check Tensorflow master address and TPU worker(s). Available devices are [_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU
```

When I open another shell and enter "ctpu status", I see that my tpu cluster is running, but I get the following panic error:

```
adrien_doerig@capser-210106:~$ ctpu status

Your cluster is running!

    Compute Engine VM:  RUNNING
    Cloud TPU:          RUNNING

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x671b7e]
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/tensorflow/tpu/tools/ctpu/commands. 
(*statusCmd).Execute(0xc4200639e0, 0x770040, 0xc4200160d0, 0xc4200568a0, 0x0, 
0x0, 0x0, 0x6dddc0)
    /tmp/ctpu- 
release/src/github.com/tensorflow/tpu/tools/ctpu/commands/status.go:214 +0x5ce
github.com/google/subcommands.(*Commander).Execute(0xc420070000, 0x770040, 
0xc4200160d0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x5)
    /tmp/ctpu-release/src/github.com/google/subcommands/subcommands.go:141 
+0x29f
github.com/google/subcommands.Execute(0x770040, 0xc4200160d0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
0xc420052700)
    /tmp/ctpu-release/src/github.com/google/subcommands/subcommands.go:385 
+0x5f
main.main()
    /tmp/ctpu-release/src/github.com/tensorflow/tpu/tools/ctpu/main.go:87 
+0xd5e
```

I tried the troubleshooting suggested here: https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting
But it did not work because everything seems normal when I enter

```
gcloud compute tpus list
```

I have also tried creating a whole new project and even using a different google account but it didn’t solve the problem. I haven't found any similar errors regarding cloud TPUs. Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out:

I needed to add a master=... parameter to my RunConfig as follows (2nd line in the following code):

```py
my_tpu_run_config = tpu_config.RunConfig(
    master=TPUClusterResolver(tpu=[os.environ['TPU_NAME']]).get_master(),
    model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir,
    save_checkpoints_secs=FLAGS.save_checkpoints_secs,
    save_summary_steps=FLAGS.save_summary_steps,
    session_config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True),
    tpu_config=tpu_config.TPUConfig(iterations_per_loop=FLAGS.iterations, num_shards=FLAGS.num_shards))
```

Now, the panic error still comes up when I enter 'ctpu status' (I do it from another shell where the virtual machine is not running), but I can run stuff on the cloud's TPUs anyways, i.e., the first error message from my original post doesn't occur anymore. So using the master=... parameter allows me to run my programs, but I am still unsure what the panic error means -- it may just be unimportant.

Answer (score 2):

The panic in `ctpu` can be ignored for now, and is caused by failure to check whether the `SchedulingConfig` field in the TPU Node object returned from the Cloud TPU REST API is populated (and therefore, not nil). This is solved by this PR:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/pull/148

and the noise will go away once this PR is incorporated into Google Cloud Shell.